ASP.NET Core Web API : basic authentication + certificate mapping
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses basic auth and SSL is required.
I have
services.AddAuthentication(o => {
                                    o.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                });

and in every controller [Authorize].
I need to add an option so client just sends certificate and map it in to user. So I added
services.AddAuthentication(
             o => {
                      o.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                  })
        .AddCertificate().

And in IIS, I added client cert mapping auth so it map client cert to Windows user testuser, and it does work correctly.
Because in inetpub/logs/, I see
2024-04-10 12:25:38 ::1 POST /sp/TestParams - 5264 testuser ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.29.2 - 401 0 0 383

so it is being mapped to 'testuser'.
But why am I getting an error:

HTTP 401 - unauthorized

What I need to add so it works as I want. Does this cert mapping work as I was thinking - that for the app it is = basic / Windows auth overall ?
I need this 'mapped' username in app later from HttpContextAccessor also.
Please advise.
Thanks and regards

Basic Auth and Windows Auth are two different things. Do not try to force both at the same time. And try just builder.Services.AddAuthentication( CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddCertificate(); What is your Authorization middleware?

but i need basic working as well - will this be exchangable? with iisdefaults i known that will work what i set up in iss, if i do this then imho only cert autch will be working?

It's actually pretty difficult to allow both certificates and another type. You could set IIS Certificate Authentication to Optional, but there's no easy way to demand the client serve up either Basic or Certificate.

if i do that this works thx but when i get username from HttpContextAccessor  i get certificate CN and not 'mapped' windows user from client cert mapping ?

ok so for future searchers...
there is no way to have both
finaly i added some flag in appsettings.json
if (a.UseCertMapingAuth)
 {
     services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate(
         o => 
         {
             o.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; 
         });
 }
 else
 {
     services.AddAuthentication(
         o =>
         {
             o.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         });
 }

and im hosting 2 projects on 2 sites one with basic +cert and second with cert only
